# logging time using httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I found the extra `%D` option in the `LogFormat` section of `httpd.conf` file.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

I was told that this is to log the time the page took to load.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. See the following site for more options:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html